# Hardware platform for building a simple always-on pc

Tags: touchscreen, performance, htpc

I am considering building a simple Kiosk PC (no keyboard or mouse, only touchscreen).

I have a spare 22" touchscreen with HDMI, DVI and VGA outputs and a USB output for touchscreen.

I want to use this with a small, low power Linux/Windows/ChromeOS PC as a media/internet center. I am not sure what hardware to use for the PC. The first thing that comes to mind is a Raspberry PI, but I am unsure if it has enough power for streaming HD Videos from LAN or internet.

Here are my mayor concerns:

1. Drivers - The monitor is a no-name (Q [link](https://www.hofer.at/de/infos-und-services/services/serviceportal/detailansicht/sis/si/8798559240193/)) and I am not sure if there are drivers for arm platform. *Clarification: my concern is about touchscreen functionality of the monitor, the display drivers are probably not the problem.*
2. Performance - Is Raspberry powerful enough to stream HD Video from internet or LAN (Amazon Video, YouTube (4K))?

I am open for any suggestions.

Comment: I wouldn't go for anything less than Pi 3 if performance is the name of the game. Connecting a monitor is not going to be an issue, HDMI is preferable as that's the connector on the Pi, so saves the hassle of adapters. Your choice of OS to an extent will have an impact on video playback. I suggest Kodi as the OS to use for anything media center related. 4K video is pushing it, a lower resolution like 1920x1080 is going to work much better.

Comment: My concern is not about display drivers, but about touch input functionality of the monitor. It works on Win 10 (and previous versions) out of the box, but in my experience getting anything but standard hardware to work on Linux is a bit more difficult. When we throw arm architecture into the mix - it could be a challenge.